# Mode expansion of wave function in 1+1D

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

Given any periodic function $$f(\sigma,\tau)=f(\sigma+2\pi n,\tau)~\forall n\in\mathbb{Z},\tag{1}$$ we know its Fourier series as
$$f(\sigma,\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n(\tau)e^{in\sigma}.\tag{2}$$
It is now given that $f$ satisfy the relationship
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\tau^2}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\sigma^2}\tag{3}$$
which is the 1+1D wave equation with wave speed 1. And we know that the general solution to it is $$f(\sigma,\tau)=f_+(\sigma+\tau)+f_-(\sigma-\tau)\tag{4}$$
where the periodicity in $\sigma$ disappeared in $f_+$ and $f_-$. As $f_+$ and $f_-$ are not periodic functions we cannot Fourier expand them like we did with $f$, then how do we determine their form (i.e. I still would like to expand them as a summation of infinite number of modes).

Comment: You are absolutely right ! Now you need to use fourier transform to mode expand the function as fourier transform is the limit in which $\tau -> \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. The spatial $2\pi$-periodicity (1) and the solution (4) imply that we can separate the [lightcone variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-cone_coordinates):
   $$\exists c:~~ f_+(\sigma_+ +2\pi)-f_+(\sigma_+)~=~c~=~f_-(\sigma_- )-f_-(\sigma_- +2\pi).$$
2. Next define new functions $$g_{\pm}(\sigma_{\pm})~:=~f_{\pm}(\sigma_{\pm})\mp \frac{c}{2\pi}\sigma_{\pm}.$$
3. It follows that the functions $g_{\pm}$ are $2\pi$-periodic, and hence have Fourier series.
4. In [string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) point 3 is used in the closed string Fourier expansion into left- and rightmovers.